# Dark Mode: white characters on the black paper

Tags: pdftex, color, environments, document-classes

Is there a function command to change the black characters on the white paper to the white characters on the black paper for the whole document?

I am using the \documentclass[article].

I am asking in general so there is no MWE. Thank you!!!

Comment: \usepackage{xcolor} 
\pagecolor{black} 
\color{white}

Comment: this is a perfect answer!

Comment: I'll put it in an answer in case somebody looks for this :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the colour of a page and text you can use the `xcolor` package:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
```